# Apache Hive - post execution hook

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I came to know that Hive hooks to interrupt hive execution flow and hook our code and hook will work first.
I want to create post execution hook or post driver hook, to capture hive query output and to apply or replace sensitive column values with static value (ex. NULL).

i gone through :[Hive execution hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461932/hive-execution-hook)

I tried with post execution hook:
im not getting how to capture query result after Hive Engine process the query before seding result to driver.

```
public class HiveExampleHook implements ExecuteWithHookContext {
public void run(HookContext hookContext) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello from the hook !!");
   /* catch output of query and feed back the output to hive execution flow to show to HIVE Client/UI. */
}
```

}

Kindly, Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.